# Removing the first line from a JSON response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

My current code is :

```
$.getJSON("https://www.domain.com/someapi/callback=?",
    function(data){
      $.each(data, function(i,item){            
        alert(item.x);
      });
  });
```

Right now I'm getting an error because they're adding a line to the top of my json response. is there a way to get rid of that line?

Thanks!

UPDATE:

I have also tried doing something like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "https://www.domain.com/someapi/callback=?",
    type: "get",
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data)
    }
});
```

but it's a crossdomain call, so i get that error.

Comment: $.getJSON need a valid json. You have to make a normal request, get the text, cut the first line and then parse it to json.

Comment: Ok, but how do i make a cross domain request with normal? See my UPDATE.

Comment: What is that line? What does the server return?

Comment: 'allowIllegalResourceCall is false.' it's to protect the api from illegal stuff :)

Comment: set `crossDomain` to true and `dataType` to `jsonp` along with the other properties when making your ajax call. Also see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3506208/jquery-ajax-cross-domain

Comment: _“it's to protect the api from illegal stuff”_ – stuff like what you are trying to do …?

Comment: look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3506208/jquery-ajax-cross-domain ,

for the crossDomain error. You can always set the dataType to "jsonp" to fix it.

Comment: I cannot use jsonp, because the first line isn't a json type..

Comment: And no, i'm not trying to do illegal stuff, I can do this on the server side, but i don't want my server to get any more hits, so i need to contact this api directly from ajax.

Answer (score 0):

Make a ajax normal request

```
$.ajax({
    url : "https://www.domain.com/someapi/callback=?",
    success : function(result){
        // So here we get the result json with an error
        // So lets say the response is something like this
        /*
            There was an error on line 35
            {
                json : true
            }
        */
        // So we remove everything before the first '{'
        result = result.replace(/[^{]*/i,'');
        //We parse the json
        var data = JSON.parse(result);
        // And continue like no error ever happened
        $.each(data, function(i,item){            
            alert(item.x);
        });
    }
});
```

I hope this work. (a cross domain request must be enabled from the server)

Comment: I can't enable the cross domain request from the server side.

Comment: If you was able to make a $.getJSON with not cross domain error this is already enabled. If it is not disabled it is probably in order not to make cross domain requests. Its a security issue.

Comment: I can make calls using jsonp or .getJSON with callback, but they put a line in the json to make sure there aren't any automatic crawlers or phishers that are out there looking for data.

Comment: If the getJSON works so will probably the code i gave you. But keep  in mind that you try to 'crawl', and thats what they try to prevent.